# Uploading and drawing from buffer

Tags: opengl

Okay, I have a `vector<float>` of x,y,z values and I'm trying to render it using opengl, Something isn't working and would like to know what I'm doing wrong, so please help!

this is how i gen the buffer

```
GLUint buffer;

int length = data.points.size() * 3 * sizeof(float);

glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, length, &data.points[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

and this is how I'm drawing it:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);                   
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, (char *)NULL);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, buffer);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument to [`glDrawArrays`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glDrawArrays.xml) is wrong. You need to pass the number of vertices there, which would probably be `data.points.size()` in your case.

Is `data.points` actually a vector of floats, like your first sentence suggests, or a vector of some kind of point structure? If it's just floats, where always 3 of them form a point, your multiplication with 3 where you calculate `length` also looks suspicious. In that case, length would just be `data.points.size() * sizeof(float)`, and the number of points passed as the third argument to `glDrawArrays` would be `data.points.size() / 3`.

Comment: anymore problems? I changed my code to fix what you suggested but still no drawing

Comment: I don't see any other problems in the code you posted. If it's not drawing anything at all, there can be a lot of reasons for that. The most common is that your geometry is not within the field of view of the camera. Are you setting a color for the points somewhere? One thing I sometimes do is use a clear color other than black. That will show you if you're drawing black points, or no points at all.

Comment: yeah my camera is fine, it appears to be drawing a single dot and nothing else... everything is in view, i guess i will have to keep checking